# Parsing using XML for Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets

Trying to scrape a specific price for google sheets. 
The element is

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center bg-grey2 brd_rht pad_none" id="id11">102.4</div>
```

while the xpath is

```
//*[@id="id11"]
```

By using

```
 =IMPORTXML("http://www.funder.co.il/fund.aspx?id=5122973","//*[@id="id11"]")
```

I get an `#ERROR!` sign. I'm quite new to using xpath, so would be glad to know what is wrong with what I did, and how is it possible to get the number 102.4 into google sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `#ERROR!` because of the `"` around `id11`; they conflict with the quotes being used in the formula. Instead use single quotes `'` around `id11`.

Your xpath selector should be `//div[@id='id11']/text()`. You can test [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

**NOTE:** Even with those changes, this won't work. If you visit the source of the [link](http://www.funder.co.il/fund.aspx?id=5122973) you're trying to pull data from and search for `id11`, you'll see that there is no value.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center bg-grey2 brd_rht pad_none" id="id11"></div>
```

This is because the data is added via jQuery when you load the page *on your browser*, so you won't be able to access it using `IMPORTXML()`. If you can figure out where that data might be coming from originally, you might be able to try this approach with that new source.

Comment: The source is from [here](https://www.tase.co.il/Heb/General/trustfund/Pages/fundmaindata.aspx?FundID=05122973), and I'm pretty sure the data is in the source here. Element `<td class="IndexesValuesRed">102.4</td>`. Still, using the xpath, I don't manage to make this work.

Comment: @Nashh Sorry, but I think you'll need to post another question. I'm not very familiar with xpath, and this is will require a more complicated query.